# How to keep the branches of a plan in bamboo specs?

Tags: branch, bamboo, specs

I use bamboo specs to backup my plans in bamboo. However, if I remove one plan and restore it back, all the branches created for this plan are missing.

I tried to use this API endpoint [Enable specs for branches](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/rest/api-group-api/#api-api-latest-plan-projectkey-buildkey-branch-enablespecsforbranches-post) but it does not seem to do any effect.

Is there any way to get the configurations and variables related to the branches of a plan in specs?

So then, if we restore back a plan that has been removed, there's no need to create branches manually and set up all needed variables specific of each branch.